# Can PWA listen in on OS events?

Tags: operating-system, progressive-web-apps, event-listener

To my knowledge, it's not possible for a regular website to have access to operating system level stuff.

In theory, PWA does have the capability to access system level stuff.  However, I think that PWA are restricted according to what the browser support.  I know that there isn't full support for all native capabilities, but I wanted to know if it's possible for PWA to listen in on Operating System events (ex. a certain application or file was opened on the client side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things like File System API's that allow a PWA to request access to local files or apps. I have yet to find one that listens to events from the OS

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of what kind of features a PWA can support on a per browser basis?